# auto refresh a div using javascript

Tags: jquery, joomla2.5

**SITUATION** I am trying to auto refresh a  tag defined within an article in Joomla 2.5

```
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js">         </script> 
     <script> 
     var auto_refresh = setInterval(
     function()
     {
     alert("testing");
     $('#results').fadeOut('slow').load('#results').fadeIn("slow");
     }, 20000);
     </script-->

     <div id="results">
     {szakitable  csv = "http://127.0.0.1/msedcl/Archives/status2.csv" csvseparator=","  width= 430}
     {/szakitable}
     </div>
```

The above code makes use of an extension called szaki tables, which allows csv file to be directly embedded into an article.
I require that the div should reload every 20 seconds so that the changes made in the csv file get reflected on the webpage. 
**PROBLEM** When i call "$('#results').fadeOut('slow').load('#results').fadeIn("slow");"
what happens is the entire page is reloaded within the div area. This is not what I require.

Any suggestion please!

Answer (score 2):

#### Did you try this?

```
$('#results').fadeOut('slow').load('{current_page.html} #results').fadeIn("slow");
```

Replace {current_page.html} with the file name of the document

#### Another way using callbacks

```
$('#results').fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $(this).load('index.html #results').fadeIn("slow")
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. When I implement your solution, by $('#results').fadeOut('slow').load('{index.php} #results').fadeIn("slow");
The problem I'm facing is that for some reason the div loads the entire page again in the small div, and also distorts all my dropdowns. I think somewhere the jquery is clashing with Joomla inbuilt query

Comment: It should be like this `$('#results').fadeOut('slow').load('index.php #results').fadeIn("slow");` check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

See `.load()` is required to load external data from other page to current page without refreshing the whole page.

As i see your code you are loading the div `#results` which won't work at all.

### From the DOCS:

#### `Loading Page Fragments:`

The `.load() method, unlike $.get(), allows us to specify a portion of the remote document to be inserted.` This is achieved with a special syntax for the url parameter. If one or more space characters are included in the string, the portion of the string following the first space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content to be loaded.

#### `example:`

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');
```

What this will load is this `gets the test.html` and `find the element with id of container` and loads it inside of element `result` on current page.

---

### So in your case:

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function(){
   alert("testing");
   $('#results').fadeOut('slow').load('targetpage.php #results').fadeIn("slow");
 }, 20000); //-------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---required
```

or if you are loading it with someother way then you can do this:

```
$('#results').fadeOut('slow').fadeIn("slow");
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. When I implement your solution, by $('#results').fadeOut('slow').load('index.php #results').fadeIn("slow");
The problem I'm facing is that for some reason the div loads the entire page again in itself, and also distorts all my dropdowns. I think somewhere the jquery is clashing with Joomla inbuilt query