# Auto refresh div itself using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to auto refresh a specific div.
I tried to use the following script:

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function () {
        $('#refresh').load('#refresh').fadeIn();
        }, 2000
);
```

However, it does not work. I think the current page url needs to added like "$('#refresh').load('{current_page.html} #refresh').fadeIn();" ([auto refresh a div using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15378310/auto-refresh-a-div-using-javascript)).

Is there any way to refresh a specific div itself using javascript or jQuery without adding to the current page url?

Comment: The parameter of  `load()` should be the URL you are requesting data from, not the `id` of the element you wish to load result into. The returned result will then be loaded into your `#refresh` element. OR to load page fragments... `$( "#refresh" ).load( "ajax/test.html #some-elem" );`

Comment: _“Is there any way to refresh a specific div itself using javascript or jQuery without adding to the current page url?”_ – why? Just _use_ the current URL, if that’s where you want to fetch the data from. (And if you don’t know _how_ to get the current URL in JS – research it.)

Comment: @ann0nC0d3r. Really thanks for your comment.

Comment: @CBroe. Thanks a lot. I will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide the url of your source to the load() function as an argument.

```
.load('sample/ajax');
```

But I guess you aught to know what goes on behind this.

You can use [ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) to load `innerHTML` of the div element without reloading the page.

Lets say you have the `loadContent()` function which returns new html content from a server. This function uses ajax to load contents dynamically.

So, you can say:

```
var myNewContent = loadContent();
$('#myDiv').html(myNewContent);
```

Now you can do this periodically using `setInterval()` function as you have done in your question.

---

Still there are few things you need to know.

1. You need to learn [ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/). Its really easy to learn this technique.
2. Your need to learn the difference between [synchronous and asynchronous calls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests). And how to handle [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).
3. You need to learn about [cross domain requests](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2013/09/jquery-cross-domain-ajax-request.html) if you are trying to get contents from a different domain than yours.

Good luck!